# Cannot read property 'status' of undefined in Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my code:

```
const db = require('../models');

const findAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await db.User.findAll();
    return res.status(200).json({
      users,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({error: error.message})
  }
}


module.exports = {
  findAllUsers,
}
```

While executing this am getting an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"

Am using, express js and sequelize to perform the action !

this is my route

```
router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    //const a = controller.allUsers;
    res.send(controller.findAllUsers());
});
```

Comment: I dont understand the downvotes. OP has provided a sample code. The `res` object is clearly undefined. You should check what arguments are you passing to the `findAllUsers` function or check if you already ended the response before.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to pass `req` and `res` as input parameter to the `findAllUsers` method?

```
router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    controller.findAllUsers(req, res);
});
```

Comment: I think you might also do this:

`router.get('/users', controller.findAllUsers);`

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

What are you accessing `status` on which might be undefined?

> ```
> res.status
> ```

So what is `res` and why might be undefined?

> ```
> const findAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
> ```

`res` is the second argument you pass to `findAllUsers`

> ```
> controller.findAllUsers()
> ```

… and you aren't passing **any** arguments to `findAllUsers` so they will **both** be undefined.

You need to pass values to the arguments you use!

---

Aside:

> ```
> res.send(controller.findAllUsers());
> ```

You're taking the return value of `findAllUsers` and sending it in the response … but you're already trying to send a response inside that function. You can't respond multiple times to the same request.

Comment: whats the solution ? as am a beginner

Comment: "You need to pass values to the arguments you use!"